# Conservation of Linear Momentum and absence of driving force

Tags: classical-mechanics

Consider this situation:

A man starts  running on a plank kept on a frictionless floor. There is no friction between the man and the plank. By the principle of conservation of momentum the plank should also move. But the necessary friction to make the plank move is absent. What is the explanation for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man cannot run on the plank if the friction between him and the plank is zero. He needs the static friction to stop his feet from slipping.

Have you ever tried to run on an icy surface? The lack of friction is what makes you slip and break your bum.

The static friction between the shoes and plank is also what causes the plank to move. So, the situation you have designed is physically inconsistent.

Either both the man and plank move, or neither of them do.

Answer (score 1):

The question itself is ambiguous. It states that the man was already on the plank when he starts running. In such a case, there will be no movement of any body as the plank is frictionless.

The Principle of Conservation of Momentum, as said by you can be applied when the man is not initially on a plank. It can be possible that the man comes running from a platform and after the platform ends, there is this plank you mentioned. Another case could be that the man was already running and then he jumps on this frictionless plank.

In both the above cases, there will be a change in momentum of both the bodies. The plank will recoil in the opposite direction in which the man was running. That can also be explained as there is a shift in the centre of mass.

In what you mentioned, the man never actually acquired a velocity. Therefore, the concept of change in momentum is useless.  The momentum never did change to have to be conserved.